# Why can't I "implements" an all-optional interface in TypeScript 2.4+?

Tags: class, typescript

I wrote some code:

```
interface IEventListener {
    onBefore?(name: string): void;
    onAfter?(name: string): void;
}

class BaseListener implements IEventListener {
    stuff() { 

    }
}
```

The intent here is that someone can derive from `BaseListener` and get correct typechecking on their `onBefore` / `onAfter` methods:

```
class DerivedListener extends BaseListener {
    // Should be an error (name is string, not number)
    onBefore(name: number) {

    }
}
```

However, I *don't* get an error in `DerivedListener`. Instead I got an error in `BaseListener`:

> Type "BaseListener" has no properties in common with type "IEventListener"

What's going on?

Answer (score 8):

The `implements` clause in TypeScript does *exactly* one thing: It ensures that the declaring class is assignable to the implemented interface. In other words, when you write `class BaseListener implements IEventListener`, TypeScript checks that this code would be legal:

```
var x: BaseListener = ...;
var y: IEventListener = x; // OK?
```

So when you wrote `class BaseListener implements IEventListener`, what you probably *intended* to do was "copy down" the optional properties of `IEventListener` into your class declaration.

Instead, nothing happened.

TypeScript 2.4 changed how all-optional types work. Previously, *any* type which didn't have properties of a *conflicting* type would be assignable to an all-optional type. This leads to all sorts of shenanigans being allowed:

```
interface HttpOptions {
  method?: string;
  url?: string;
  host?: string;
  port?: number;
}
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
const pt: Point = { x: 2, y: 4 };
const opts: HttpOptions = pt; // No error, wat?
```

The new behavior as of 2.4 is that an all-optional type requires *at least one matching property* from the source type for the type to be considered compatible. This catches the above error and also correctly figures out that you tried to `implements` an interface without actually doing anything.

Instead what you should do is use *declaration merging* to "copy down" the interface members into your class. This is as simple as writing an interface declaration with the same name (and same type parameters, if any) as the class:

```
interface IEventListener {
    onBefore?(name: string): void;
    onAfter?(name: string): void;
}

class BaseListener {
    stuff() { 

    }
}
interface BaseListener extends IEventListener { }
```

This will cause the properties of `IEventListener` to also be in `BaseListener`, and correctly flag the error in `DerivedListener` in the original post.